# even index is being omitted while traversing the list in python

Tags: python, list

I want to get even indexed numbers from the python list
here is my code snippet:

```
for i in array:
        if array.index(i) % 2 == 0:
            print(str(i) + " >> index: " + str(array.index(i)))
```

The list I am providing is as below:

`-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41`

But in output its not showing me the number `84` having `index 16` `even is it divisible by 2`

Why is it omitting the `index 16` also sometimes I'm getting odd index and even indexes both!

Comment: What are the values in your array? `array.index` finds the *first* index with that value. That's not necessarily your current index.

Comment: ```-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41``` these are values in the list i understand the what you said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your values aren't unique, `array.index` may find the index for a *different* value than your current one. You should use `enumerate` for explicit indexes:

```
for i, value in enumerate(array):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        ...
```

But [list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) can already do exactly that without the extra check:

```
for i in array[::2]:
    print(i)
```

Comment: in slicing it shows the first index of 84 which is 9, but using enumerate solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you have twice `84`, `array.index(84)` returns `9` for both of them, to get only even items you may use `enumerate` like

```
for idx, value in enumerate(array):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        print(value, ">> index:", idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

`array.index(i)` is the index of the first occurrence of `i`. If you're processing a duplicate element of the list, this will return the earlier index, not the current index.

For instance, `84` is at index 9 and 16. When you get to index 16, `array.index(i)` returns `9`, which isn't even, so nothing is printed.

You can use `enumerate()` to get the indexes along with the elements, and test that.

```
for i, el in enumerate(array):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(str(el) + " >> index: " + str(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

As the above answers explained it -

You are doing indexing the wrong way.
I will show you how you can do it easily.

```
odd_i = [] 
even_i = [] 
for i in range(0, len(test_list)): 
    if i % 2: 
        even_i.append(test_list[i]) 
    else : 
        odd_i.append(test_list[i]) 
  
res = odd_i + even_i
```

even_i will contain even indices and odd_i will contain odd indices.
You can achieve this by slicing too.